# how to center Items that are not in div or span in html/css

Tags: html, css, center, division

I sometimes build my html website and need to add few things after i finish which i didnt expect to put at the beginning for example like an image between the lines so i just opem img tag and put the image without putting it in a div or span. so the problem is i dont know how to center it then. Is there anyway to center an item that doset have a parent container? here is an example code

```
<html><img src="img.jpg" alt="img"></html> <style>text-align: center;</style>
```

the problem with this code is that it dosent center anything I also tried to use literly all properties that can center like "justify-content: center; or align-items: center;" but the img dosent move at all and I only can move it by using padding or margin which is not the best way to do.

Does anyone have an Idea of how i can center an item that dosent have an parent Container like div or this dosent work in html/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the display property as "flex".

```
<html><img src="img.jpg" class="Myimg"></html>
```

```
.Myimg
{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: thank your for your answer. It actually works but not exactly the way i wanted casue in this case i have to put the img in a div and then give this div a display: flex; to be able to use justify-content: center; and this was what i didnt want to use. I wanted it without a div but still thak you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix your code so that it would work, be sure to add `html` within the `style` section of your code. Like this:

`<html><img src="img.jpg" alt="img"></html> <style>html { text-align: center; }</style>`

But that will make everything centered. If you want only the image to be centered, do this:
`<html><img src="img.jpg" id="myimage" alt="img"></html> <style>#myimage { text-align: center; }</style>`

**OR**

There's an alternate solution (which someone else already posted here), about using `display:block` and `margin:0 auto` -- that's also doable.

There are 2 ways that this could work for you:

Option 1:

`<html><img src="img.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" alt="you should probably leave alt blank if the image is decorative, otherwise actually describe what it is"></html> <style>html { text-align: center; }</style>`

Option 2:

`<html><img src="img.jpg" id="#myimage" alt="img"></html> <style>#myimage{ display:block;margin: 0 auto; }</style>`

Ultimately, it comes down to actually learning CSS and how stylesheets work. You might want to do some learning about that, find some "learn CSS" videos on youtube and websites -- this is sorta core stuff, so if you don't understand it yet, research the basics a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

For an image specifically, you could use `display: block` and `margin:0 auto` like: `<img src="img.jpg" style="display:block; margin:0 auto;" alt="img">`

Additional Reading: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-an-image-in-css/